# Did somebody tried to recompile NHibernate for .NET 4.0 Beta 2?

Tags: nhibernate, .net-4.0

Did somebody tried to recompile NHibernate for .NET 4.0 Beta 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from having to update target framework versions for all projects to .Net 4, there is one compilation error remaining. NHib uses the `ISet<T>` defintion from Iesi.Collections whereas there is now an `ISet<T>` in System.Collections.Generic. There are 102 of these ambiguous reference errors.