# System.ExecutionEngineException With Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, windows-services, windows-xp-sp3

I have a windows service accesing other project (no matter what, cause It doesn't even start)

The thing is that I have a `System.ExecutionEngineException` while starting the service (in this code)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    const IConfig config = null;
    _weatherService = new WeatherService();
    _weatherService.setup(config);
    _weatherService.init();
    _weatherService.start();
}
```

I'm in a windows XP and .NET 3.5 (No, I'm not from the past) and I can't even start the service from a Console Application. Do you know how to solve it? (If you need any more info, please just ask for it)

Thank you so much guys ☺

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try disabling concurrent garbage dumping -- seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec(v=vs.90).aspx

If you're program is performance heavy, then concurrent garbage collection's memory movement could throw this exception.

[Why does concurrent GC sometimes cause ExecutionEngineException (per MSDN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531860/why-does-concurrent-gc-sometimes-cause-executionengineexception-per-msdn)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception(v=vs.90).aspx